# How do i get the correct getTimezoneOffset()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to get the correct timezoneOffset by using javascript, if a user has disabled "Automatically adjust time clock for Daylights saving time" on his or her computer.

For example if i turn on automatically adjust DST i get -420 in june, and -480 in January for Pacific Time zone.
However if i disable Automatically adjust DST i get -480 for both January and June.

Is there any way to correct this behavior so that i get the expected DST even if automatically adjust DST time is checked off?

Comment: It's not possible to do.

Comment: well, you can ask a user.

Comment: And what if the user did this for a specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I've used a little while back ([source](http://michaelapproved.com/articles/timezone-detect-and-ignore-daylight-saving-time-dst)), hope this helps.

```
function TimezoneDetect(){
    var dtDate = new Date('1/1/' + (new Date()).getUTCFullYear());
    var intOffset = 10000; //set initial offset high so it is adjusted on the first attempt
    var intMonth;
    var intHoursUtc;
    var intHours;
    var intDaysMultiplyBy;

    //go through each month to find the lowest offset to account for DST
    for (intMonth=0;intMonth < 12;intMonth++){
        //go to the next month
        dtDate.setUTCMonth(dtDate.getUTCMonth() + 1);

        //To ignore daylight saving time look for the lowest offset.
        //Since, during DST, the clock moves forward, it'll be a bigger number.
        if (intOffset > (dtDate.getTimezoneOffset() * (-1))){
            intOffset = (dtDate.getTimezoneOffset() * (-1));
        }
    }

    return intOffset;
}
```

To detect DST without using `getTimezoneOffset` use this:

```
var rightNow = new Date();
var jan1 = new Date(rightNow.getFullYear(), 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var temp = jan1.toGMTString();
var jan2 = new Date(temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf(" ")-1));
var std_time_offset = (jan1 - jan2) / (1000 * 60 * 60);

var june1 = new Date(rightNow.getFullYear(), 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
temp = june1.toGMTString();
var june2 = new Date(temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf(" ")-1));
var daylight_time_offset = (june1 - june2) / (1000 * 60 * 60);
var dst;
if (std_time_offset == daylight_time_offset) {
   dst = "0"; // daylight savings time is NOT observed
} else {
   dst = "1"; // daylight savings time is observed
}
```

Comment: As OP stated - the timezone settings are incorrect on the user's machine. So not sure how relying on unreliable data could produce something other than garbage

Comment: He didn't say the timezone was incorrect, he said the "Automatically adjust time clock for Daylights saving time" was disabled.

Comment: isn't it the same to what I said but wrapped into a "user friendly" phrase? If you don't know the timezone name, you don't know when it's DST to be applied and if you don't know if it was turned off - you cannot make a correct decision, you may only try to guess.

Comment: @zerkms I've updated my answer - you are correct, but no need to guess :-)

Comment: Roni i tried the above function, but i get 0 (daylight savings time is not observed) when i select pacific timezone on my windows computer and uncheck the option to autumatically adjust DST settings.  But daylight savings time is observed in the Pacific Time Zone.